# value is type of a and b

Tags: sql

For a given database

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
```

The question is:
*Find the printer makers which also produce PCs with the lowest RAM and the highest-speed processor among PCs with the lowest RAM. Result set: maker.*

Lets split the query!

- *Find the printer makers which also produce PCs*

> SELECT DISTINCT maker from product Group By maker,type HAVING type
>   IN('Printer','PC')

I think this is wrong because IN('Printer','PC') is like as OR not AND

- *PCs with the lowest RAM*

> SELECT model,speed FROM pc WHERE ram=(SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc) as lowestRam

- *the highest-speed processor among PCs with the lowest RAM*

> ```
> WHERE
> lowestRam.speed=(SELECT MAX(speed) FROM pc WHERE ram=(SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc))
> ```

query itself!

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT model,speed FROM pc WHERE ram=(SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc)) as lowestRam
INNER JOIN product 
ON product.model=lowestRam.model
WHERE
lowestRam.speed=(SELECT max(speed) FROM pc WHERE ram=(SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc))
Group By maker,type HAVING type IN( 'Printer' ,'PC')
```

Unfortunately when I submit the query on checking site, it produces 1 extra incorrect result :(

Question comes from [Link](http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php?LN=25).
There are 2 steps of query verification. The 2nd step shows only the difference between user and correct result :(

Comment: What is the extra unexpected result?

Comment: I use this site to learn sql http://www.sql-ex.ru (question #25). There are 2 steps of query verification. The 2nd step shows only the difference between user and correct result :(

Comment: I have little suggestion: almost all queries, requiring DISTINCT keyword to work properly, are not correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM    
 (SELECT DISTINCT model,speed FROM pc WHERE ram=(SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc)) as lowestRam
 INNER JOIN product 
       ON product.model=lowestRam.model AND
 lowestRam.speed=(SELECT max(speed) FROM pc WHERE ram=(SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc))
 Group By maker HAVING maker IN( SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type='Printer')
```

Answer (score 5):

This should resolve your problem :

```
select distinct maker from Product
where type = 'Printer' and maker in (select maker
from Product join PC on Product.model = PC.model
where ram = (select min(ram) from PC) and speed = (select max(speed) from PC 
where ram = (select min(ram) from PC)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks correct (though a little over complicated) from what I can see.  If you could provide the sample data and the "extra incorrect result" then it would be easier to track down the issue.

Here's my simplified version of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.maker
FROM product p1, pc
WHERE  p1.model = pc.model
   AND pc.speed = (SELECT MAX (speed)
                   FROM pc
                   WHERE ram = (SELECT MIN (ram) FROM pc))
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 from product p2 where maker = p1.maker and p2.type = 'Printer')
```

Comment: "Wrong number of records (more by 2)" I think that product.TYPE IN ('PC', 'Printer') is wrong because it is like OR not AND. In database there are makers which only produce Printer or pc

Comment: I updated the query to enforce that the maker also produces printers.

Comment: +1 Still wrong but closer :) "Wrong number of records (more by 1)"

Comment: I created some test data and it worked for me.  Again, without seeing the data you are using I can't find your specific issue.  The link you provide requires a login so we won't be able to access it.

Comment: I can't see the data too:( Look at mine answer, I finally made it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT p.maker 
FROM
(
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ram ASC,speed DESC) AS Rnk
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN (SELECT maker
            FROM Product 
            WHERE type IN ('PC','printer')
            GROUP BY maker
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type)=2
           )p1
ON p1.maker = p.maker
INNER JOIN PC  
ON PC.model = p.model
)t
WHERE Rnk=1
```

Comment: Do you know what language it's using? T-SQL? PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT maker
  FROM product
 WHERE model IN (
    SELECT p.model
      FROM pc p JOIN printer r 
                  ON (p.ram =(SELECT min(ram) FROM pc) AND  
                      p.speed=(SELECT max(speed) FROM pc WHERE ram = 
                              (SELECT min(ram) FROM pc))
                     )
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct maker
  from product,pc
 where product.model in
       (select model
          from pc
         where speed in (select max(speed) from pc group by ram)
           and ram in
               (select ram from pc where ram in (select min(ram) from pc)))
   and product.maker in (select maker from product where type = 'printer')
and Product.model=PC.model

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT G.MAKER FROM PC F,PRODUCT G
WHERE 
F.MODEL = G.MODEL
AND F.SPEED=
(
  SELECT MAX(E.SPEED) FROM PC E WHERE E.RAM =
  (
   SELECT MIN(C.RAM) FROM PC C,PRODUCT D WHERE D.MAKER IN 
          (SELECT A.MAKER FROM PRODUCT A,PRINTER B WHERE A.MODEL=B.MODEL)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct maker from product, PC where product.model=PC.model and product.type='PC' and speed=(select max(PC.speed) from PC where ram=(select min(PC.ram) from PC))